# How to pass polygon to query.geometry with ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have to highlight district boundary and corresponding point. So I am trying to do like below code. But I don't know how to pass district polygon geometry to `query.geometry`.

```js
var queryTask = new QueryTask(".../arcgisserver/rest/services/CRD/CRD2/MapServer/0");

var query = new Query();

query.geometry = event.mapPoint; //your district polygon geometry    
query.outFields = ["*"];    
query.returnGeometry = true;

//Execute task    
queryTask.execute(query, showResults);

function showResults (results) {

    var resultItems = [];
    var resultCount = results.features.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < resultCount; i++) {
        var featureAttributes = results.features[i].attributes;
    }

}
```

Is it possible to pass polygon geometry into query task. If so how can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can passe a Polygon Geometry , in your case I think , when you are clicking in the map you want first to get the District polygon , and after you'll perform the query on the `CRD/CRD2/MapServer/0` by passing the distric poly if i've understand !

it's quite easy ,
I dont know if you're creating your own widget or a you write a legacy code,

So , create first a [FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html)(*1) for your distrcit Layer :
it has a [queryfeatures](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#queryfeatures) method that helps to get geometry of the clicked point ( if it has ) , declare it as class varibale if possible , that can be accessible in the class functions

```
var districtFLayer = new FeatureLayer("URL_TO_YOUR_DITRICT_MAPSERVER_LAYER");
//".../arcgisserver/rest/services/District/MapServer/1" by exemple
```

then create a methode that return the geometry District by seraching by District Name Text

(here by exemple I'm using the attribute search `Name` for the district layer the query would be

`query.where ="Name ='" + dsitrictName+"'";`)learn more about [query.where](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/query.html#where)

```
//AMD declaration Style 
makeQuery: function(dsitrictName){
   var query = new Query();
   query.where ="Name ='" + dsitrictName+"'";
   //query.spatialRelationship = Query.SPATIAL_REL_INTERSECTS;  //no for this if it's not query with geometry 
   // point that intersect with the District polygon  spatial relation ship
   query.returnGeometry = true;
   query.outFields = ["*"]; // if you want all attribute being returned
   var geometry = null;
   districtFLayer.queryFeatures(query, function (featureSet){
       //check existance of a Distric at that point
       if(featureSet.features.length>0)
           geometry = featureSet.features[0].geometry;
   });
   return geometry;
}

// leagacy declaration
function makeQuery(mapPoint){
   var query = new Query();
   query.where ="Name ='" + dsitrictName+"'"; // name of the district
   //query.spatialRelationship = Query.SPATIAL_REL_INTERSECTS; //no for this if it's not query with geometry 
   // point that intersect with the District polygon  spatial relation ship
   query.returnGeometry = true;
   query.outFields = ["*"]; // if you want all attribute being returned
   var geometry = null;
   districtFLayer.queryFeatures(query, function (featureSet){
       //check existance of a Distric at that point
       if(featureSet.features.length>0)
           geometry = featureSet.features[0].geometry;
   });
   return geometry;
}
```

After in your above code use the [features-query-complete](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#event-query-features-complete) event to ensure that the request (ajax ) was done and there is a returned geometry :

```
...
var pointClick = event.mapPoint;
var geometry = makeQuery(pointClick ); // this.makeQuery(pointClick ) in AMD 
districtFLayer.on("features-query-complete",function(result){

    if(geometry != null){ // if there is a returned geometry
    // **** HERE your above code ***** //
       var queryTask = new QueryTask(".../arcgisserver/rest/services/CRD/CRD2/MapServer/0");
       var query = new Query();
       query.geometry = geometry ; //the returned district polygon geometry    
       query.outFields = ["*"];    
       query.returnGeometry = true;

       //Execute task    
       queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
       .... // rest of code 
    }
});
```

Info: 
if you want to  highlight  the returned geometries 
use [Graphics](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphic-amd.html) and add them to a [GraphicLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html)

(*1) module `"esri/layers/FeatureLayer"`

Comment: If you provide the whole class code , I can help you to highliight the results

Comment: exactly same thing I wanted to do but values will come from drop down. that thing I am getting

Comment: You mean that `event.mapPoint` come form DropDown menu ? 
if so, is it a point ?

Comment: no its district name so its polygon

Comment: so `event.mapPoint` is a text or a geometry !
if you can share the code , i can't figure now your probleme !

Comment: in your above code there is query for polygon .query will return geometry of that map click instead of this can I get geometry by using where clause

Comment: I've edit the code , try to passe the text in the makeQuery function and make the correct attribute search in the `query.where`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35160/discussion-between-user5841808-and-brimos-bor).

Answer (score 2):

you can pass any valid geometry object (including [esri/geometry/Polygon](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/polygon-amd.html)) to query.geometry as soon as you have a reference to it.

Comment: i need to do two queries one to get district boundary extent and that extent i need to pass in above code